# How do I get the border the move up and down when "Up" and "Down" button is clicked?

Tags: jquery

I would just like the border to move up and down when I click the up or down button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#up").click(function() {
    $("#up").prev().css("border", "2px solid blue");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#down").click(function() {
    $("p").next().css("border", "2px solid blue");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="one">paragraph 1</p>
<p id="two">paragraph 2</p>
<p id="three">paragraph 3</p>
<p id="four">paragraph 4</p>

<button id="up">Up</button>
<button id="down">Down</button>
```

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: So for starters, up/down operating off the starting point.  As far as I can tell your code doesn't have any way of knowing what the starting/current point is.

Comment: None of your paragraphs start with a border, so what should happen the first time when either up or down is clicked? Also, you don't need multiple document ready calls. Everything can go in one.

Comment: Lets say #four { border:2px solid blue; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#up").click(function() {
    if ($("p.with-border").prev("p").length > 0) { // is there prev paragraph?
      $("p.with-border").prev("p").addClass("with-border");
      $("p.with-border").last().removeClass("with-border");
    }
  });
  $("#down").click(function() {
    if ($("p.with-border").next("p").length > 0) { // is there next paragraph?
      $("p.with-border").next("p").addClass("with-border");
      $("p.with-border").first().removeClass("with-border");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.with-border {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="one">paragraph 1</p>
<p id="two">paragraph 2</p>
<p id="three">paragraph 3</p>
<p id="four" class="with-border">paragraph 4</p>

<button id="up">Up</button>
<button id="down">Down</button>
```

Comment: Nice Aleksandar Belic! I like the way you have written the code.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it (comments in code):

```js
var ps = $('p'),      // cache the paragraphs
    currentIndex = 3; // starting at paragraph 4

$("#up").click(function() {
  currentIndex -= 1;             // decrement index
  if (currentIndex < 0) {
    currentIndex = ps.length - 1;  // set back to bottom item
  }
  
  ps.removeClass('border');
  ps.eq(currentIndex).addClass('border')
});

$("#down").click(function() {
  currentIndex += 1;              // increment index
  if (currentIndex == ps.length) {
    currentIndex = 0;             // set back to top item
  }
  
  ps.removeClass('border');
  ps.eq(currentIndex).addClass('border')
});
```

```css
.border {
    border:2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="one">paragraph 1</p>
<p id="two">paragraph 2</p>
<p id="three">paragraph 3</p>
<p id="four" class="border">paragraph 4</p>

<button id="up">Up</button>
<button id="down">Down</button>
```